# SSL certificate verify failure every other time

Tags: ruby, openssl

The following code gives an error on heroku, but only every other time.

```
host = "api.pagepeeker.com"
cert = "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
(0..19).map do |i|
  ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
  ssl_context.set_params(ca_file: cert, verify_mode: 1)
  s = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(TCPSocket.open(host, 443, nil, nil), ssl_context)
  s.sync_close = true
  s.hostname = host
  begin
    s.connect
  rescue
    "error"
  else
    "ok"
  ensure
    s.close
  end
end.join(' ')

#=> ok error ok error ok error ok error ok error
```

The error is: `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed`

This corresponds to `Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("https://api.pagepeeker.com"))`

I am stumped by the alternating failures and successes. Upgrading OpenSSL from 0.9.8k to 1.0.1e did not help.

Comment: Have you tried running with `Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)` and then specifying `ca_path` in http options?

Comment: Try closing the connection in an `ensure` block

Comment: added ensure block, no changes.

Comment: @Alex I'm trying to reproduce this bug using only the OpenSSL library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the second answer. The first was too long to tack on, and this is a different finding.

It appears part of the problem is pagepeeker.com is not sending all the certificates required to validate the chain. That is, its not sending required intermediate certificates.

If pagepeeker.com does not send all the required certificates, then the client encounters the "which directory" problem. Its well known in PKI, and it means a client has no idea which X500 directory it should query to find the missing intermediate certificates.

Now, back to your problem: you might be seeing an intermittent problem because there could be one misconfigured server in a load balanced environment. Part of the solution to your problem may be the pagekeeper.com server sending all required certificates.

---

Here's the certificates sent by pagekeeper.com:

```
$ echo "GET / HTTP\1.1" | openssl s_client -connect api.pagepeeker.com:443 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 description = 8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl, C = RO, CN = api.pagepeeker.com, emailAddress = alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 description = 8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl, C = RO, CN = api.pagepeeker.com, emailAddress = alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 description = 8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl, C = RO, CN = api.pagepeeker.com, emailAddress = alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/description=8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl/C=RO/CN=api.pagepeeker.com/emailAddress=alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/description=8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl/C=RO/CN=api.pagepeeker.com/emailAddress=alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1957 bytes and written 648 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 92E4B4B744DDFE63EBD2EDC8D0D6065FF9D05589FD10A05E0C971F6CE0B2526D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: CE01E4B9BFB3D0F3B95F81004013320DE44BFBE399AB84ABA047C0064DBDABC200CE5472F74EA5881BF99F66A58729F7
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 63 03 ce 7b 9b 75 3b 4d-7f 1c dd f0 6d 56 1c 32   c..{.u;M....mV.2
    0010 - c2 af 84 b2 1c c8 aa 18-6c 90 54 68 46 96 8f 5d   ........l.ThF..]
    0020 - 26 11 e7 37 89 e4 a4 29-ff 26 04 20 c8 08 f4 8a   &..7...).&. ....
    0030 - de cf 38 b1 57 83 ae 45-41 51 48 c1 7c b9 df 0f   ..8.W..EAQH.|...
    0040 - 6a e1 c7 75 93 b4 24 5c-5f 63 97 ce 2d b7 12 eb   j..u..$\_c..-...
    0050 - 05 a8 57 d3 4d af 31 5d-18 b3 f8 8e 02 70 6f 2f   ..W.M.1].....po/
    0060 - fe 33 18 c6 7d 83 58 76-37 5f 59 9a ed e5 28 ae   .3..}.Xv7_Y...(.
    0070 - d5 5a 9f a4 46 13 55 f3-14 aa 47 f5 b6 63 e8 76   .Z..F.U...G..c.v
    0080 - 82 bf 2c f9 35 9a 01 fc-3d e9 2e 8f 1f ca a5 67   ..,.5...=......g
    0090 - 3b 55 6f f4 4d c1 fa 79-40 20 6d 82 f7 49 58 7a   ;Uo.M..y@ m..IXz

    Start Time: 1380751071
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
DONE
```

---

If you look at something from, for example Google, you will see the entire chain is sent:

```
$ echo "GET / HTTP\1.1" | openssl s_client -connect encrypted.google.com:443 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=*.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4410 bytes and written 448 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: D87198A1294D6B41660C0DA153137348B6F65BBD2E6B7D410104964C21A33682
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 2967DF01FECCBC2EF444C7723BD3CA105C522BFC613D568F8D65D3D28F2A8CD6EF031D9B6D3132DE3D8B3364ED061A41
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 8b 66 a6 c9 dd b3 2e c8-f6 2e 87 18 3c 90 8b 57   .f..........<..W
    0010 - 77 18 39 be 93 40 fe 20-6a 08 1d f3 54 3a f1 22   w.9..@. j...T:."
    0020 - d3 eb 51 8c 56 23 bc 87-51 0e 12 6b 23 57 ba 67   ..Q.V#..Q..k#W.g
    0030 - f2 5b c2 78 d7 8f 06 99-42 97 7c ce 7f 99 4a 74   .[.x....B.|...Jt
    0040 - ef ec 55 f2 77 64 f3 3e-c8 24 e7 45 92 1b 54 ef   ..U.wd.>.$.E..T.
    0050 - 79 f2 3b 0f 69 35 84 7d-cd 21 0a 45 b6 8a b9 e4   y.;.i5.}.!.E....
    0060 - 61 9a 8e 7b c5 e9 26 82-56 27 b4 f3 25 b8 82 5b   a..{..&.V'..%..[
    0070 - 19 8b ce b9 bf 61 e2 3e-1c 08 16 7e af 91 e9 44   .....a.>...~...D
    0080 - f9 53 75 cd 59 e0 80 50-03 09 07 67 e1 2d bf 6d   .Su.Y..P...g.-.m
    0090 - aa d4 b9 3a                                       ...:

    Start Time: 1380750955
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
DONE
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough answer! Can this explain the alternating successes and failures?

Answer (score 1):

They are using a host certificate that does not chain back to a [trusted] root certificate. You should probably be seeing the error more often (every time?).

You might need to call `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` with a file that contains the required StartCom root certificate. You can get the StartCom root from http://www.startssl.com/?app=26. You want the one that includes "StartCom Certification Authority", which I believe is in the bundle http://www.startssl.com/certs/ca-bundle.pem. There's a few in that file, but OpenSSL handles the concatenation fine as long as you are willing to accept the risk of the additional roots.

```
$ echo "GET / HTTP\1.1" | openssl s_client -connect api.pagepeeker.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/description=8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl/C=RO/CN=api.pagepeeker.com/emailAddress=alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
 1 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/description=8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl/C=RO/CN=api.pagepeeker.com/emailAddress=alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5552 bytes and written 648 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: D761D5D91D9BD18933CD68A37A9E65CC9CF6D0A0F28A8CB1D07C34C0E7B98253
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 43E285E1113C70B0767EE4B62B042166D1BFC86B62BAFE0F3338DB2771479EE51C99C19DC6E09E98E44FB79130206B9F
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c7 19 e2 ed e1 7b a1 84-40 84 3a 0d f0 73 e2 4c   .....{..@.:..s.L
    0010 - 2b 79 a1 3e 22 24 9a a8-d3 3a 4a 51 8d 6f 54 a5   +y.>"$...:JQ.oT.
    0020 - ea 64 e4 68 3c 2b dd f2-e8 80 b8 e0 be 52 c1 ad   .d.h<+.......R..
    0030 - ae 44 19 76 7d a2 64 19-e1 6d bb c1 8a 80 a0 d9   .D.v}.d..m......
    0040 - 42 29 99 99 16 47 34 1e-44 11 10 be 9a 6a 95 6b   B)...G4.D....j.k
    0050 - 09 55 ef 28 8f 44 8f 04-1d bd aa 79 b8 07 59 5f   .U.(.D.....y..Y_
    0060 - 1f 4e bd 00 ef e3 31 3d-6e 1f e8 79 6b bb fa 4a   .N....1=n..yk..J
    0070 - b9 8a cb 3a 4e 7e 8e bb-7a e7 81 b7 1f af d0 50   ...:N~..z......P
    0080 - 84 70 99 77 b3 81 1d 0e-7f 04 4e 52 7e 95 fa 05   .p.w......NR~...
    0090 - 19 be 78 e8 e6 bb cd 3c-08 49 dd 77 64 92 f7 eb   ..x....<.I.wd...

    Start Time: 1380706251
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
DONE
```

When I use the Startcom CA bundle and the `-CAfile` option, I cannot reproduce the failure, even across consecutive runs:

```
$ echo "GET / HTTP\1.1" | openssl s_client -connect api.pagepeeker.com:443 -CAfile startcom-ca-bundle.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 description = 8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl, C = RO, CN = api.pagepeeker.com, emailAddress = alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/description=8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl/C=RO/CN=api.pagepeeker.com/emailAddress=alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
 1 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/description=8CTO6gSuxeRRsIXl/C=RO/CN=api.pagepeeker.com/emailAddress=alexandru.florescu@gmail.com
issuer=/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5552 bytes and written 648 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 9A0E34E509AA7C2EED12E58D0D80B078B39D4A5A5C981E510D9D190E5F76B911
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 2F447B622ACBB0006DC121FA43FB562ACE2BDEAF73D3EC887AF7BC22548392AB42E3625530874EA541C569DB7543E273
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c7 19 e2 ed e1 7b a1 84-40 84 3a 0d f0 73 e2 4c   .....{..@.:..s.L
    0010 - 46 cf b7 fd 33 95 88 14-fb da 08 4b 0a 58 e0 55   F...3......K.X.U
    0020 - 31 ff 2a cf ff fb 65 a3-b4 db 8f 5f 65 6c 72 15   1.*...e...._elr.
    0030 - ba ce c3 84 4f 83 9f 01-3d d4 87 f8 a1 eb bb b5   ....O...=.......
    0040 - 1b a2 9a de 94 55 86 ad-d7 e7 29 ed f0 98 a4 5f   .....U....)...._
    0050 - 4d 93 f6 a7 db 15 7f d3-b3 ca 63 2c a9 8d 69 b2   M.........c,..i.
    0060 - 77 3e a6 28 76 ba d3 a7-f7 5c 20 88 75 23 71 7d   w>.(v....\ .u#q}
    0070 - 99 62 b4 fd b9 09 1c ec-90 2d a0 c1 27 d0 23 61   .b.......-..'.#a
    0080 - 18 da 47 17 06 3c 29 34-05 3e f3 d2 22 29 09 cc   ..G..<)4.>..")..
    0090 - d2 41 b7 8d 29 14 c2 88-3b ad 67 2a 88 25 e1 9b   .A..)...;.g*.%..

    Start Time: 1380708844
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been a misconfiguration on one of the PagePeeker load balancers. It has been fixed at the time the issue was mentioned.